# Bower v1.5.2 : EINVALID errors when installing dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, bower, bower-install

Since updating bower to version 1.5.2, a get `EINVALID` error when bower is installing :

- font-awesome : The "main" field cannot contain font, image, audio, or video files
- select2 : The name has to end with a lower case character from a to z
- bootstrap-datetimepicker : The "main" field cannot contain minified files
- ...

With previous version of bower (1.3.12), there was no error.

Is that possible to ignore this errors?

My bower.json file :

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "components/jquery#~2.1.1",
    "js-cookie": "~2.0",
    "bootswatch-scss": "~3",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.3.*",
    "select2-bootstrap-css" : ">=1.4.6",
    "tinymce": "4.2.*",
    "bootstrap-table": "~1.8",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "~1.4",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~4.15",
    "moment": "~2.10",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.4",
    "hinclude": "0.9.*"
  }
}
```

**Update**

At this time, I regress to version 1.3.12

```
npm uninstall bower -g
npm install -g bower@1.3.12
```